# the location of "interacting"?

Tags: meaning, gerunds

Could you explain in detail which one is correct in grammar or what is the difference if both are correct in grammar? Thank you in advance.

- Errors arise primarily within *the interacting wave zone*.
- Errors arise primarily within *the wave interacting zone*.

Comment: The zone where the waves interact.

Comment: Are you sure that *interacting* is the best choice of word?  In many physical systems, waves are assumed to be independent, i.e. one wave can pass through another unaffected.  Their amplitudes add, and they *appear* to be interacting, but at the mathematical level they are superposed *without* interaction.  It's possible that this doesn't apply to the case you have in mind, but if it does, you might be able to rephrase your description of the "interaction zone".

Answer (score 1):

In general, the first one is preferable.  (I'm assuming it's a zone where there are interacting waves.)  The second one sounds, on its own, as if you're describing a zone that interacts with waves.  However, if for reasons of emphasis you've previously described it as the "wave interacting zone," the second form would be as easily understood.